# ajax image loading breaking full SSL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssl

My site is full SSL besides the images that get pulled from this `ajax` call

```
    $.ajax({
        url : 'index.php?route=taobao/taobao/related_products&product_id=<?php echo $product_id;?>&cid=<?php echo $cid;?>&tm=<?php echo $tm;?>',
        dataType : 'html',
        beforeSend : function(){
            $('#related_products').append('<div class="loading_related" style="margin:15px auto;text-align:center"><img src="public/image/load5.gif" /></div>');
        },
        complete : function(){
            $('.loading_related').remove();

            $('#related_products img').each(function() {
                var src = this.src.replace(/(http\:\/\/img\d\.tbcdn\.cn)/, "https://img.alicdn.com");
                $(this).attr('src', src);
            });
        },
        success : function(html){
            $('#related_products').html(html);
        }
    });
```

I am unable to access the template file to change the urls so instead I am changing the url via

```
$('#related_products img').each(function() {
    var src = this.src.replace(/(http\:\/\/img\d\.tbcdn\.cn)/, "https://img.alicdn.com"); 
    $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```

This works well and the whole site will be ssl but I am encountering mixed content errors (I guess because the flash of unsecured requests?) Is there anyway I can have my site fully ssl without `mixed-content` errors?

Comment: Why don't you change uri protocol **before** appending images into the DOM???

Comment: @A.Wolff I've tried moving the function to beforesend but it doesn't seem to do anything then

Answer (score 0):

Try to set URI protocol to these images before appending them to the DOM. Here is an example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?route=taobao/taobao/related_products&product_id=<?php echo $product_id;?>&cid=<?php echo $cid;?>&tm=<?php echo $tm;?>',
  dataType: 'html',
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('#related_products').append('<div class="loading_related" style="margin:15px auto;text-align:center"><img src="public/image/load5.gif" /></div>');
  },
  success: function(html) {
    var newHTML = $('<div/>', {
      html: html
    }).find('img').prop('src', function() {
      return this.src.replace(/(http\:\/\/img\d\.tbcdn\.cn)/, "https://img.alicdn.com");
    }).end().html();

    $('#related_products').html(newHTML);
  }
});
```

And btw, your complete callback becomes useless here if there is only one element `.loading_related` at time.